# access hidden field(created in javascript) in struts2 action

Tags: javascript, struts2

How can I access a hidden field (which was created in javascript) in Struts2 action class?

Example : 
    var hidNode = document.createElement("input");
    parNode.appendChild(hidNode);

```
hidNode.type = "hidden";
hidNode.id = "hidId";
hidNode.name = "hidName";
```

Now, after submitting the form, how can I access this hidden value in action class ?

Answer (score 1):

The field will be injected in the Action through a Setter, matching by name.

so if you create with javascript a field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidName" id="hidId" />
```

, to retrieve it in the Action you must have the following:

```
private String hidName;
public void setHidName(String hidName){
    this.hidName = hidName;
}
```